# Populating sqlite3 database in Python loop

Tags: python, sqlite

I have constructed a database but when I loop through my data to populate it, I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: no such column: tmp1
```

Code:

```
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE(X REAL, Y REAL)")

for i in xrange(0,5):
   tmp1 =  array[i,0]
   tmp2 =  array[i,1]
   with con:
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO TESTTABLE VALUES(tmp1,tmp2)""")
```

Basically I have a big array that I want to transfer into a database. This probably isn't the most efficient way of going about it. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert values into a row, you need to pass those values along as SQL parameters to the `.execute()` call:

```
with con:
    for i in xrange(0,5):
        tmp1 = array[i, 0]
        tmp2 = array[i, 1]
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO TESTTABLE VALUES(?, ?)""", (tmp1, tmp2))
```

The `?` characters are parameters, and they are filled, in order, by values takes from the second argument to `.execute()`, a tuple. The above code will insert the numbers 0 through to 4 as pairs into the database.

Names in the SQL code have *no* correlation to names you define in Python, values can only be passed in explicitly.

Comment: So do I replace the ? with the variable names I assigned, (X,Y) as well? Could you edit your answer to show how cur.execute("""INSERT INTO TESTTABLE VALUES(tmp1,tmp2)""") should be changed. cur.execute("""INSERT INTO TESTTABLE VALUES(?,?)""",(tmp1,tmp2)) doesn't work.

Comment: I'm inserting the value of an array element, not the entire array.

Comment: @Griff: Can you elaborato on why my answer "doesn't work" for you? What types are `tmp1` and `tmp2` here? What is the error that you receive?